# How do I comment header files?

Tags: c++, header-files, doxygen

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------
** functions used for converting between different data types
** ---------------------------------------------------------*/

#ifndef TYPECONVERTER_H_INCLUDED
#define TYPECONVERTER_H_INCLUDED


/**
    converts binary to decimal
    @return converted decimal number
*/
int toDecimal(bool binary[], int noOfNumbers);

/**
    converts decimal to binary and stores it in a given array
*/
void toBinary(int origin[], bool binary[], int noOfNumbers);

#endif // TYPECONVERTER_H_INCLUDED
```

How do I comment what this header does, so Doxygen understands it? Right now it just assigns the top comment to the first function.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HHqo.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doxygen has a `\file` command, which marks a comment block as documenting a certain file. When used as `\file filename.ext`, it will assign it to the file `filename.ext`. As just `\file`, it applies to the file in which it occurs.

Example:

```
/**
 @file
 functions used for converting between different data types
*/
```

Comment: /*
 * @file functions used for converting between different data types
 */ It doesn't work like this. What did you mean?

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Example added. You need the line end, otherwise doxygen will interpret "functions" as the argument to `\file`.

Comment: No what he means is is to create an extra comment at the top of your header file like: `/** @file headerfilename.h */. This is necessary to include the documentation of this file.

Comment: @gmug Not quite; I added an example of what I meant. You don't *have* to provide the file name, an `@file` on its own line is enough.